# How to replace html tags between the double curly braces in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, community, salesforcedx

**
From this given string we need to replace all html tags as blank which located into the double curly braces'{{''}}'.
**

```
String Temp = '';String temp2 = '';String temp3 = '';String temp4 = null;String temp5 = null;String splitVal = '';
String str = '<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"></head><body style="background-color:#ffffff;padding:72pt 72pt 72pt 72pt;max-width:468pt"><p style="padding-top:15pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">Id: {{Id}}</span></p><p style="padding-top:7.5pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">Opportunity accountid: {{Opportunity_accountid}}</span></p><p style="padding-top:7.5pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">Opportunity: {{Opportunity}}</span></p><p style="padding-top:7.5pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="font-weight:700">Opportunity: {{</span><span style="font-style:italic">Opportunity</span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">}}</span></p><p style="padding-top:7.5pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="font-weight:700">Opportunity: {{</span><span style="text-decoration-skip-ink:none;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:none;font-weight:700;text-decoration:underline">Opportunity</span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">}}</span></p><p style="padding-top:7.5pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="font-weight:700">Opportunity: {{</span><span style="color:#4a86e8;font-weight:700">Opportunity</span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">}}</span></p></body></html>';
integer count = str.countMatches('{{');

for(Integer i=1; i<=count; i++)
{
    Temp = str.substringBetween('{{', '}}');
    system.debug('temp-->'+temp);
    temp5 = Temp.replaceAll('\\<.*?\\>','');
                system.debug('temp5-->'+temp5);
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. This community is not used to simply provide answers, but to help with solving concrete issues. Please modify your question to describe what steps have you taken so far to resolve it.

Comment: @ytiq Hi I try to replace the html tags from the given string but it shows on 1 value which exist on curly braces .

Comment: @ytiq as you said i modified my question and add my steps which i have to try to resolve this

Comment: and what is your debug output?
1. You do not remove `{{ }}` from the string, so I think it takes same substring each time
2. Your Regex only matches opening tag, but not closing

Comment: This question is an almost exact duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347164/how-to-replace-all-html-tag-between-the-double-curly-braces-in-a-given-string - but I can't flag this as duplicate since the other question does not have an upvote or an answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working code. I used standard method plus used indexes to replace, because it's easier to work with them

Comment: Do not repost questions, please. You can always [edit] your post to improve it, but you haven't really made any changes to the post. Additionally, do not post under multiple accounts. Use the Contact link at the bottom of this page to have your accounts merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your substrings and replace them with `str.stripHtmlTags()`

```
String Temp = '';String temp2 = '';String temp3 = '';String temp4 = null;String temp5 = null;String splitVal = '';
String str = '<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"></head><body style="background-color:#ffffff;padding:72pt 72pt 72pt 72pt;max-width:468pt"><p style="padding-top:15pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">Id: {{Id}}</span></p><p style="padding-top:7.5pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">Opportunity accountid: {{Opportunity_accountid}}</span></p><p style="padding-top:7.5pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">Opportunity: {{Opportunity}}</span></p><p style="padding-top:7.5pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="font-weight:700">Opportunity: {{</span><span style="font-style:italic">Opportunity</span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">}}</span></p><p style="padding-top:7.5pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="font-weight:700">Opportunity: {{</span><span style="text-decoration-skip-ink:none;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:none;font-weight:700;text-decoration:underline">Opportunity</span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">}}</span></p><p style="padding-top:7.5pt;color:#000000;padding-left:0;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:15pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:15pt;margin-left:15pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;text-align:left;padding-right:0"><span style="font-weight:700">Opportunity: {{</span><span style="color:#4a86e8;font-weight:700">Opportunity</span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-style:normal">}}</span></p></body></html>';
integer count = str.countMatches('{{');

System.debug('###str.length() = ' + str.length());
for(Integer i=1; i<=count; i++)
{
    Integer i1 = str.indexOf('{{');
    Integer i2 = str.indexOf('}}');
    if (i1 == -1 || i2 == -1) {
        break;
    }
    Integer length = i2 - i1;
    System.debug('###i1 = ' + i1);
    System.debug('###i2 = ' + i2);
    String s1 = str.substring(i1, i2 + 2);
    String s2 = str.substring(i1  + 2, i2).stripHtmlTags();

    System.debug('###s1` = ' + s1);
    System.debug('###s2 = ' + s2);
    str = str.replace(s1, s2);
    System.debug('###str = ' + str);

}
```

Comment: In given output its give me only Id but if you beautify the html string yo can see the other names like opportunity . So I want all values which have between the curly braces but the for loop stuck on first curly braces value.

Comment: try it again, updated the answer

Comment: as I said in your try you weren't removing `{{ }}` from your string

Comment: as it is working now, please accept my answer, so the question can be closed

Comment: In the given output it remove all the html tags between the curly braces and also remove the curly braces So i want in my desired output like all html tags are removed the remaining value shown in curly braces i don't want to remove curly braces.

Comment: I done it Thank For your Help.

Comment: np, you can do it by saving current position and update replacement. Glad I was able to help